# Workflow issue in microsoft dynamics NAV 2016

Tags: dynamics-nav-2016

I am working on workflow  to approve  journal  batch  .
I have an  error message :
You must define a table relation between all records used in events Microsoft dynamics NAV 2016 .

I already define all the  step     window (event-condition-response)      smtp window  , notification  window ,job queue.
I just enabled the workflow  and  the message error occur.
Could you give me advice.

Comment: I noticed  I m getting on the debugger  :
          IF WorkflowTableRelation.ISEMPTY THEN
            ERROR(ValidateTableRelationErr);     

What could cause  that error .
Could you give me your sugesstions ?
Regard Rodd!

Comment: That means you must fill the `WorkflowTableRelation` table, isn't it obvious?

Comment: It fill up already .

Comment: Look through previous lines of code. There should be `setrange` or `setfilter` comands. So set the same filters to your table and you will see no lines. That means you lacking some settings. As error says you must define all relations.

Comment: I just recreated a new workflow from a template and now I m getting  an another errror .
I m excuting  the  send  approval  request   (button)  and I m getting  the following error message :   
This record  is not supported  by related  approval workflow .
What could cause this problem ?
I already  create and enabled  the  approval   workflow  from a template and set up  smtp mail  server and job queue and notification   .

Comment: I created a workflow from a Purchase Invoice Approval  template.

But I wish to use it for a  batch file for payement journal .